# Как написать в афише "с 10 августа"?

Tags: орфография, числительные, окончания, сокращения

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как правильно написать в афише "с 10 августа". Даты окончания нет. 
"С 10 августа", "с 10.08"? Правильно ли написание "с 10-го августа"?

Comment: Указание в афише года, в т. ч., не просто желательно как признак хорошего тона, но и важно для истории.

Answer (score 2):

Лучше написать "С 10 августа", если эта информация является ключевой. Если информация о дате второстепенная, можно написать "С 10.08". Вариант "С 10-го августа" не рекомендуется.

По последнему пункту процитирую справочник Мильчина.

> 4. Не требуют наращения падежных окончаний следующие порядковые числительные, обозначенные арабскими цифрами: 
>     ...
>     б) Даты
>      (годы и числа месяца), если родовое слово следует за ними.  Например:
>      1972 год, 5 мая.

Comment: Большое спасибо!